# How to match a string (?,?,?) in Java

Tags: java, regex

My input string is of the form:
String input = "(?,?,?)";

I am not able to come up with a valid regex to identify such strings

I have tried with following regex:

```
String regex = "(\\?,*)";
```

Assertion fails with the above regex for input strings such as (?,?) or (?,?,?,?)

Comment: Note regarding answers below: if (?) case is valid, use * . If (?) case is not valid, use + .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could match `(?` and then repeat 1+ times `,?` and match `)`.

If a single question mark is also valid, you could change the quantifier from `+` to `*`

```
\(\?(?:,\?)+\)
```

Explanation

- `\(\?` Match `(?`
- `(?:,\?)+` Non capturing group, repeat 1+ times `,?`
- `\)` Match `)`

In Java

`final String regex = "\\(\\?(?:,\\?)+\\)";`

[Regex  demo](https://regex101.com/r/T31ZtP/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/9FdHnE)

Comment: Thanks. What if i  have to match  0 or more of ? , meaning, my input string could be of (?) or (?,?,?....) , can the regex be extended as below:
final String regex = "\\(\\?(?:\\)\\)+(?:,\\?)+\\)"

Comment: Then you could change the quantifier to * https://regex101.com/r/F6I0ao/1

Answer (score 2):

A general regex pattern would be:

```
\(\?(?:,\?)*\)
```

Sample script:

```
String input = "(?,?,?,?)";
if (input.matches("\\(\\?(?:,\\?)*\\)")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
\(        match a literal opening parenthesis
\?        match a single ?
(?:,\?)*  then match ,? zero or more times
\)        then match closing )
```